# .Net CF CultureInfo for language not installed

Tags: localization, internationalization, windows-mobile, windows-ce, cultureinfo

We have a variety of Windows CE 5.0, 6.0, 7.0 and Windows Mobile 5.0 devices.  Our apps use Compact Framework 3.5, developed with Visual Studio 2008.  The apps support multiple languages; the user is allowed to select the language when logging into the app.

Our issue is, while Visual Studio supports Spanish (United States) as a language choice, none of our devices have this installed.  As a workaround, I can use the Spanish (Mexico) es_MX language, which is installed, and modify the DateTimeFormat and NumberInfo properties as run-time.  However I don't feel comfortable with this approach, if there is a better way.  Will I run into some other issues by taking this approach?  Is there a preferred alternative?  Note, .Net CF 3.5 does not support the CultureAndRegionBuilder class.

Comment: I fear the storage of Windows Mobile 6.x CE 5/6 is to limitted to support all language sets. I would go with your local user settings for Number, Dateformat etc.